# get coordinates of a marker symbol in mapbox-gl-js and center on it

Tags: marker, mapbox-gl-js

I have this symbol on a map

```
map.addLayer({
    "id": "home",
    "type": "symbol",
    "source": "property",
    "interactive": true,
    "layout": {
        "icon-image": "rocket-15",
    }
});
```

I would like to zoom in to this marker and center on it.

So far I have tried this:

```
map.featuresIn({ layer: 'home' }, function(err, features) {
    console.log(features);
    map.flyTo({ center: features[0].geometry.coordinates,zoom: 11 });
});
```

I omit the coordinates argument, so I refer to it directly (as stated in API). However, the 'features' arrive empty and I can never fly

Answer (score 1):

`featuresIn` does not return features' geometries by default. For that, you must include the `includeGeometry: true` parameter.

You will find [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/center-on-symbol/) helpful!